# Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column 'broken_plural' at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a new database in mysql according to this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-database.html

```
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS `nouns` (
          `id` int(11) unique auto_increment,
          `vocalized` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `unvocalized` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `wordtype` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `root` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `original` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `mankous` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `feminable` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `number` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `dualable` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `masculin_plural` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `feminin_plural` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `broken_plural` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `mamnou3_sarf` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `relative` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `w_suffix` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `hm_suffix` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `kal_prefix` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `ha_suffix` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `k_suffix` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `annex` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          `definition` text,
          `note` text
        )  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
insert into nouns (vocalized, unvocalized, wordtype, root, original, mankous, feminable, number, dualable, masculin_plural, feminin_plural, broken_plural, mamnou3_sarf, relative, w_suffix, hm_suffix, kal_prefix, ha_suffix, k_suffix, annex, definition, note) values ('مفرد/تكسير','مفرد/تكسير','اسم فاعل','','','المنقوص','التأنيث','جمع تكسير','التثنية','"ج. مذ. س."','"ج. مؤ. س."','الجمع','','نسب','ـو','هم','كال','ها','ك','"إض. لف."','',':لا جذر:لا مفرد:لا تشكيل:لا شرح');
```

This script is what I am using to fill my database. In the actual script there are about 28 thousand more insert lines. None of these lines seem to have extremely large `values` fields. I've tried using the `MAX` for the size of `varchar(MAX)` as well as `TEXT` and `LONGTEXT`. None of these seem to work.

This is the values clause for the row in question at the time of error

```
values ('خَاتِمٌ','خاتم','اسم فاعل','ختم','','','Ta','مفرد','DnT','','Pf','":خَوَاتِمُوَخَوَاتِيمُ:خُتُمٌ"','','','','','','','','','". 1. ""وَضَعَتْ فِي أُصْبُعِهَا خَاتَماً مِنْ ذَهَبٍ"" : أيْ حَلْقَةً لِلأُصْبُعِ. 2.""خَاتَمُ الزَّوَاجِ"" : حَلْيُ الأُصْبُعِ الَّذِي يُقَدِّمُهُ الْخَطِيبُ لِخَطِيبَتِهِ عُرْبُوناً عَلَى ار"','')
```

The error states "at row 1" but some 150 rows are affected before the error occurs. Is there something special I need to do in mysql to support multibyte characters besides `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`?

I've verified that the line in question IS NOT the longest line the the list of `insert` commands. Can anyone come up with a reason why this line is corrupt but others post fine?

```
insert into nouns (vocalized, unvocalized, wordtype, root, original, mankous, feminable, number, dualable, masculin_plural, feminin_plural, broken_plural, mamnou3_sarf, relative, w_suffix, hm_suffix, kal_prefix, ha_suffix, k_suffix, annex, definition, note) values ('خَاتِمٌ','خاتم','اسم فاعل','ختم','','','Ta','مفرد','DnT','','Pf','":خَوَاتِمُوَخَوَاتِيمُ:خُتُمٌ"','','','','','','','','','". 1. ""وَضَعَتْ فِي أُصْبُعِهَا خَاتَماً مِنْ ذَهَبٍ"" : أيْ حَلْقَةً لِلأُصْبُعِ. 2.""خَاتَمُ الزَّوَاجِ"" : حَلْيُ الأُصْبُعِ الَّذِي يُقَدِّمُهُ الْخَطِيبُ لِخَطِيبَتِهِ عُرْبُوناً عَلَى ار"','')
```

Comment: The error message is very clear. The data you are trying to insert is to big to fit one of the columns

Comment: increase the varchar size of your column `broken_plural`, alter it

Comment: and maybe some of these lines (likely the first insert) has some error (some coma or quote..).

Comment: If you guys hadn't noticed I have already tried increasing the size of the `broken_plural` column. I've increased it to `LONGTEXT` which holds 4,294,967,295 characters. That honestly should be plenty.